# Renderplot will not render the default value of a selectinput for multiple plots in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app that has multiple plots from different data frames. What I want is to have a selectinput for each plot where the user's selection changes the dataframe that is being plotted, with some other user inputs depending on the plot. When I do this, only one plot will render while the other plots need to have a value changed before they render. I have the following reprex to help explain what I mean.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library (dplyr)
library(wordcloud)
library(wordcloud2)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

Survey1_Together <- read.csv(text = '"Answer", "Score"
                  "A", 20
                  "B", 10
                  "C", 14')


Survey1_user1 <- read.csv(text = '"Answer", "Score"
                        "A", 10
                        "B", 5
                        "C", 4')

Survey1_user2 <- read.csv(text = '"Answer", "Score"
                        "A", 10
                        "B", 5
                        "C", 4')

Survey2_Together <- read.csv(text = '"Answer", "Score"
                  "A", 200
                  "B", 120
                  "C", 140')

Survey2_user1 <- read.csv(text = '"Answer", "Score"
                        "A", 150
                        "B", 50
                        "C", 40')

Survey2_user2 <- read.csv(text = '"Answer", "Score"
                        "A", 150
                        "B", 70
                        "C", 100')

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(width =4),titlePanel(h2("Wordcloud Survey 1", align = "center"))),
  fluidRow(HTML("<br>")),
  fluidRow(HTML("<br>")),
  fluidRow(flowLayout((tags$div(selectizeInput("which", "Choose a user", choices = c("Together", "User 1", "User 2")), align = "center")),
                      (tags$div(sliderInput(inputId = "num", label = "Range of word usage", value = c(0,10000), min = 1, max = 10000), align = "center")), align = "center")),
  fluidRow(HTML("<br style = 'line-height: 100px'>")), 
  fluidRow(column = 12, (tags$div(wordcloud2Output("wordcloud1", height = "600px"), align = "center")))
  ,

  fluidRow(column(width =4),titlePanel(h2("Wordcloud survey 2", align = "center"))),
  fluidRow(HTML("<br>")),
  fluidRow(HTML("<br>")),
  fluidRow(flowLayout((tags$div(selectizeInput("which2", "Choose a user", choices = c("Together", "User 1", "User 2")), align = "center")),
                      (tags$div(sliderInput(inputId = "num2", label = "Range of word usage", value = c(0,1000), min = 1, max = 1000), align = "center")), align = "center")),
  fluidRow(HTML("<br style = 'line-height: 100px'>")), 
  fluidRow(column = 12, (tags$div(wordcloud2Output("wordcloud2"), align = "center"))),
  fluidRow(HTML("<br style = 'line-height: 200px'>")),

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  datasetInput1 <- reactive({ 

    switch(input$which,
           "Together" = Survey1_Together,
           "User 1" = Survey1_user1,
           "User 2" = Survey1_user2)})

wc1 <- reactive(
    datasetInput1() %>%
                   filter(Score %in% (input$num[1]:input$num[2]))) 

  output$wordcloud1 <- renderWordcloud2({wordcloud2(wc1(), color = "random-light", widgetsize = 10, size = 2)
  })
  datasetInput2 <- reactive({
    switch(input$which2,
           "Together" = Survey2_Together,
           "User 1" = Survey2_user1,
           "User 2" = Survey2_user2)})
  wc2 <- reactive(datasetInput2() %>%
                   filter(Score %in% (input$num2[1]:input$num2[2])))

  output$wordcloud2 <- renderWordcloud2({wordcloud2(wc2(), size = 1, fontFamily = "Arial", fontWeight = "bold",  color = brewer.pal(8, "Set1"), minSize = .5, gridSize = 15, minRotation = 0.01, maxRotation = 180, rotateRatio = 1 )})

  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here, the first wordcloud will render while the second one needs to have a value changed before it can render. Does anyone know what I can do to make both plots render with the default value?

So far I have tried: Using unique values, using req functions (which I've seen in similar forums but it did not work here), and rearranging the code blocks. I apologize for any unnecessary libraries or if the slider range don't make sense, I pulled this code from a much larger project I am working on and I am using dummy variables here. The same problem happens in the larger project with the first plot rendering and all others needing a variable to change before rendering. Am I missing something as to how to make them all render? Thank you

Comment: I am sorry if I am not explaining it well. I would like both of the plots to render with their default variables when the app is launched. With the code the way it is only the first plot is rendering at the start of the app, while the other one needs to have the selectinput changed before it renders.

Comment: I see - I was able to reproduce the same problem. I saw this [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/281) and this [issue](https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2/issues/37)on github. It looks like both `renderWordcloud2` methods are called. I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I appreciate you trying!